# Is there any way to quickly add class to an HTML element in JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am trying PhpStorm and I coming over from VS Code.

I am used to adding classes and ids to my html elements like this:
`element.class` or `element#id`. I got very used to it and now I very much miss it.

Is there any similar way to add classes and ids to html elements in PhpStorm?

Comment: This looks more like a question about the difference between PHP and C# or something, than about the editor?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-zen-coding-support.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/) and it is supported in JetBrains IDEs (IDEA based at least).

Just press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (default shortcut, can be changed in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet`) to expand the sequence, e.g. `p.red[TAB]` to make `<p class="red">[CARET]</p>`

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-zen-coding-support.html